# I am having truble with geting the software version in Baxter

Tags: ros, rosparam, baxter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to Baxter and I have trouble getting the software version for Baxter.
I am trying to execute this commend

```
rosparam get /rethink/software_version
```

but I get this error

```
ERROR: Parameter [/rethink/software_version] is not set
```

any one know how to solve this problem.

---

Edit: thank you I appreciate your help.

I have another problem when I try to run this code:

```
rosrun baxter_tools enable_robot.py -e
```

it dose not work and I got this error:

```
[WARN] [WallTime: 1453764465.061960] RobotEnable: Failed to retrieve robot version from rosparam: rethink/software_version
Verify robot state and connectivity (i.e. ROS_MASTER_URI)
```

how can I solve this issue;

thank you
MiMo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225025/i-am-having-truble-with-geting-the-software-version-in-baxter/) by [MiMo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25725/mimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) on 2016-01-25**:
make sure the robot is on and that baxter.sh is sourced in every terminal in which you put baxter-specific commands. If you have more problems you should really email the brr-users list: brr-users@rethinkrobotics.com

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-01-26**:
@MiMo: please don't post answers if you're not *answering* the question. For updates to your own question, please just edit it, using the *edit* link/button. I've merged your update into your question, but please keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source your baxter.sh file before trying to get the rosparam? The baxter.sh file configures your shell to talk to the ROS Master running on the Baxter robot. If the software_version parameter was set in the Parameter Server running on the Baxter's ROS Master, then you won't be able to access if it if you aren't connected.

You can also try emailing the brr-users list for Baxter-specific questions, or searching their Google Groups page:

https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/forum/?utm_medium=landing+page&utm_source=Act-On+Software&utm_content=landing+page&utm_campaign=&utm_term=Research%20Forum#!forum/brr-users

---

Originally posted by [jackie](https://answers.ros.org/users/23055/jackie/) with karma: 296 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) on 2016-01-26**:
you also need to edit the baxter.sh file with a new robot/workstation install to set the correct values for the robot and your workstation.